# BigQuery select and alias field from nested array without grouping

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I have some data in a BigQuery table where one of the fields is an array of structs. I'm trying to essentially do a `SELECT *` but alias the nested fields in the array. Here's a quick example:

```
with array_of_records as (
  select
    'field1' as regular_field,
    [struct ('arr_1a' as field_1, 'arr_1b' as field_2), struct ('arr_2a' as field_1, 'arr_2b' as field_2)] as array_field
)

select
  regular_field,
  array_agg (
    struct (
      array_entry.field_1 as field_a,
      array_entry.field_2 as field_b
    )
  ) as array_field
from array_of_records, unnest(array_field) array_entry
group by 1
```

Is there a way to do this without having to as an `array_agg` and `group_by`? I'm asking because the table has a large number of fields and I want to avoid having to group by all except the nested array field. I realize I can also aggregate every single column with something like `any_value()` but that doesn't seem like a particularly clean solution either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do know from experience that doing this as a subquery can be a big win:

```
select regular_field,
       (SELECT array_agg(struct(array_entry.field_1 as field_a, array_entry.field_2 as field_b))
        FROM  unnest(ar.array_field) array_entry
       ) as array_field       
from array_of_records ar;
```

This avoids the "global" aggregation, so the data does not have to move among lots of nodes.

Comment: @PrratekRamchandani . . . Cool.  I had encountered a similar problem about a year ago and thought that this simple change would have a large impact.